# Ошибка в mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Получаю ошибку:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expression
>
> import reposActions
>   Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
>     Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => Promise' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
>   index.d.ts(21, 3): 'type' is declared here.

Код в компоненте:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  loadRepos: (query: string) => {
    dispatch(reposActions.loadRepos(query))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Импортирую: `import * as reposActions from '../actions/reposActions';`

Код reposActions.js:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';

export function loadReposSuccess(repos) {
    return {
        type: types.LOAD_REPOS_SUCCESS,
        repos
    };
}

export function loadRepos(query = 'react') {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return axios
            .get(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${query}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(loadReposSuccess(response.data.items));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                throw err;
            });
    };
}
```

Почему не удается получить loadRepos?

Comment: не хватает return в mapDispatchToProps, return {loadRepos...}

Comment: Там же стрелочная функция.

Comment: стрелочная функция не делает return в данном варианте, вот такой вариант даст нужный результат: const mapDispatchToProps = { loadRepos }